# Syntax error when accessing property by variable?

Tags: javascript, properties

I have a json variable stored in $("#budget").data('allocations')

I can access it's data like this:

```
id = "5";
alert( $("#budget").data('allocations')[id].amount );
```

But I need to access it like this:

```
var id = "5";
var field = "amount";

alert( $("#budget").data('allocations')[id].[field] );
```

Using the variable in the property name causes it to fail.

missing name after . operator (referring to [field])

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, `.xxx` can be replaced with `["xxx"]` and there is no limit in combining. Just use the same logic you used for `id`:

```
$("#budget").data('allocations')[id][field]
```

Whenever the key is in a variable, replace `.key` with `[variable]`. So, `obj.key1.key2` becomes `obj[variable1][variable2]` with the same logic.

Comment: Oh nice, my only issue was the period. $("#budget").data('allocations')[id].[field] should have been $("#budget").data('allocations')[id][field] Thank you!

Comment: @2bytes: On SO, saying thanks is accepting the answer, thanks :)